# Erro de font-face ao publicar projeto

Tags: css

Estou com um projeto em MVC.

Quando executado em `localhost` as `fonts` vão normal, porém ao publicar no servidor elas dão erro.

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.1');
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.0.1') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.0.1#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Erro

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>   http://areacursos.net/Content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>   http://areacursos.net/Content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf

Arvore de arquivos:

```
Web/Content/css
        - font-awesome.min.css 
Web/Content/fonts
        - FontAwesome.otf
        - fontawesome-webfont.svg
        - fontawesome-webfont.woff
        - glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
        - glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
Web/Views/Shared
        - _Layout.cshtml
Web/Views/Home
        - index.cshtml
```

Comment: Isso acontece em que *browser*? Eu estou com um problema semelhante, mas só no Firefox, e também estou bastante interessado numa solução... (no meu caso uso Bootstrap, mas a fonte problemática é a mesma)

Comment: @mgibsonbr Testei no IE e no Chrome e nenhum dos dois foi!

Comment: Como está sua árvore de diretórios? Posta onde estão seus htmls e seus resources (css,js,imagens,..)

Comment: @LeoCBS, pronto

Comment: Essa pasta Web é a public_html/www?

Comment: Sim... seria a www

Answer (score 1):

Problemas com WebFonts são comuns principalmente com a `FontAwesome`. Podendo variar desde a font's corrompida a letras maiúsculas no nome da font.

No seu caso o problema é bem simples, ao verificar o console de erro do Google Chrome e na própria pergunta percebemos que a font apresenta um erro 404.

Verificando o servidor http://areacursos.net/content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff percebemos que realmente existe um erro 404 e também percebemos que existe uma razão para isso.

**The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.**

Aparentemente sua hospedagem não está configurada para este tipo de arquivo e por isso apresenta um erro 404.3 mesmo com o arquivo existindo. Eu mesmo na última semana encontrei um problema similar com `JSON`.

Entre em contato com sua empresa de hospedagem e solicite para ativar o suporte.

Agora sobre o problema com a font no **Firefox**, [isso é uma história a parte](https://github.com/MaxCDN/bootstrap-cdn/issues/27%29), basicamente o Firefox e o IE não permitem requisições de font's de um servidor externo como um CDN. Sendo necessário tanto uma configuração do servidor como do cliente.

O código abaixo deve resolver o problema.

```
# Apache config
<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>

# nginx config
if ($filename ~* ^.*?\.(eot)|(ttf)|(woff)$){
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

Mais informações sobre este problema com Firefox no link http://davidwalsh.name/cdn-fonts